# JSONIX / AJV: how to use Xinclude inside JSONIX for validation?

Tags: json, node.js, xml, xinclude, jsonix

I try to use JSONIX on nodejs and using the AJV for validation of the incoming XML.

Normally I use something like this:

News.xml:

```
<news xmlns="http://news24.tt/news">
  <publisher>
    <author>Max Mustermann</author>
    <company>NEWS24</company>
    <resort>Sports</resort>
  </publisher>
  <topic>HSV wins against FCB!</topic>
  <article>Bla bla ... </article>
</news>
```

but now I will use this

Author.xml:

```
<publisher xmlns="http://news24.tt/news">
  <author>Max Mustermann</author>
  <company>NEWS24</company>
  <resort>Sports</resort>
</publisher>
```

News.xml:

```
<news xmlns="http://news24.tt/news" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
  <xi:include href="Author.xml" />
  <topic>HSV wins against FCB!</topic>
  <article>Bla bla ... </article>
</news>
```

Is it possible to use JSONIX and AJV to validate even such structures?
I even have a XSD and the generated JSON-Schema.

kind regards

Markus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jsonix does not support `xi:include` at the moment. It's not impossible though but not implemented. Therefore AJV also won't be able to do anything as it validates on the JS object level, not on XML.

**Disclaimer** I'm the author of Jsonix.